# mapping of data from multiple tables in DB to another table in different DB

Tags: java, sql

1). i have 2 DB A & B

2). in one DBA 3 tables and 1 in another DBB

3). i have to insert and update in the in DBB from DBA

4).insert from DBA to DBB if that data is not present in DBB

5). how can i do this in my batch file(java)

Comment: *"how can i do this"* You write some code. Are you asking how to access DB from Java? If so, then search the web, aka do some **research**. --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: No i wrote my sql command to select data from both the DB tables and insert sql also....but i should write come java code so that i can compare the  tables in DBA and DBB so that the datas that are not in DBB thatare inserted from DBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First you need two database connections.
- Using first database connection fire select query on required table and get the results and store those result in some Map or bean.
- Pass that data to another function which is going to use other database connection. Create insert query and add values to that query using above input data (i.e bean or map) and then fire that insert query.
- Don't create connections in loop. Create one connection pass it on to DAO layer, get the data and close the connection.
- Pass on that data to another API, where you will use another connection to 
  insert data.

I would have provided you the code, but then it will not be helpful for you, because then you won't be able code by yourself ever in life....

You need to dive in...face the exceptions, face the errors and see the magic after resolving those issues.

Do let me know in case you need more information about the approach you need to solve the problem.

Comment: can you give an sample code

Comment: Sample code for what ? For creating database connections ?

Comment: *"Create insert query"*? An `INSERT` *statement* is not a *query*. A `SELECT` statement is a query.

Comment: Sorry for that @Andreas.